# 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

encryption in this way works fine but when i try to use Decrypt it gives me padding Error i don't know why ?? Here is main Method and used Key & IV Value.
& BaseEncryptor Class Where i Use Encryption & Decryption Method
I tried uesing every type in padding but it also doesn't work.I tried to change block size and key size it also doesn't work.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string key = "ldm_encrypt_code1234567891234567";
            string IV = "9876897123651785";
            string encstr = BaseEncryptor.EncryptUsingAes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"Hello Code"), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IV)); //Encryption
            string xc=BaseEncryptor.Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encstr), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(IV)); //Decryption way

        }
        public class BaseEncryptor
        {
    
            public static string EncryptUsingAes(byte[] inputTextByte, byte[] privateKeyByte, byte[] sharedIVKeyByte)
            {
                using (var aesEncryption = AesEncryptionType(privateKeyByte, sharedIVKeyByte))
                {
                    // Convert string to byte array                
                    byte[] dest = new byte[inputTextByte.Length];
    
                    // encryption
                    using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor(aesEncryption.Key, aesEncryption.IV))
                    {
                        dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(inputTextByte, 0, inputTextByte.Length);
    
                        encrypt.Dispose();
                    }
                    return BitConverter.ToString(dest).Replace("-", "");
                }
            }
            public static AesCryptoServiceProvider AesEncryptionType(byte[] privateKeyByte, byte[] sharedIVKeyByte)
            {
             //used in both encryption & Decryption
                var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                aes.BlockSize = 128;
                aes.KeySize = 256;
                aes.IV = sharedIVKeyByte;
                aes.Key = privateKeyByte;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; //Mode
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  //Padding not working in case of none or Zeros
                return aes;
            }
            public static string DecryptUsingAes(byte[] inputTextByte, byte[] privateKeyByte, byte[] sharedIVKeyByte)
            {
                using (var aesDecryption = AesEncryptionType(privateKeyByte, sharedIVKeyByte))
                {
                    // Convert string to byte array                
                    byte[] dest = new byte[inputTextByte.Length];
    
                    // encryption
                    using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aesDecryption.CreateDecryptor(aesDecryption.Key, aesDecryption.IV))
                    {
                        dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(inputTextByte, 0, inputTextByte.Length);
                        decrypt.Dispose();
    
                    }
                    // Convert byte array to UTF8 string
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dest); ;
                }
            }
            public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
            {
                string plaintext = null;
                // Create AesManaged    
                using (var aesDecryption = AesEncryptionType(Key, IV))
                {
                    // Create a decryptor    
    
                    // Create the streams used for decryption.
                    using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesDecryption.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV))
                    {
                        string result;
                        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                        {
                            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                            {
                                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                                {
                                    result = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return plaintext;
                }
    
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: The ciphertext must not be UTF8 encoded in the `BaseEncryptor.Decrypt()` call, but must be hex decoded, since it is hex encoded at the end of `BaseEncryptor.EncryptUsingAes()`. Also, a `null` is returned in `BaseEncryptor.Decrypt()` since neither `result` is returned nor `plaintext` is assigned.

Comment: yes you Are Completely right, i convert cipher text to hexa byte array and it worked for me thank you very much.